# passing string by value vs passing every character by value

Tags: c++

```
void func(char c) {}
void func(std::string) {}

int main() {
    std::string s("HelloWorld");

    // method 1
    func(s);

    // method 2
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        func(s[i]);
    }
}
```

why is passing by value in case of the second call OK? is it not effectively copying the same number of characters in the end? Or are they actually the same and I'm missing something?

Comment: What is the purpose of the actual code youre writing and have a problem with? Should the function only process a single character at a time, or to process a whole string?

Comment: You should also count the number of function calls in the two cases. And also do some measurements if you're wondering what is fastest. And of course don't forget about passing references.

Answer (score 1):

The copy of `std::string` will do an allocation (unless small string optimization), whereas passing `char` as parameter would probably be done by register.

Pass `std::string` by const reference

```
void func(const std::string&);
```

Comment: Not all systems have registers enough to pass values in registers. Like the 32-bit x86 architecture for example. But that's not the biggest deal, the biggest deal is the number of *function calls* being made. There's the big difference.

Comment: My problem was you have to copy any value at least two times. For example, if you are assigning a char to a cell in a char array, then you need to use the assignment operator which I'm assuming will take the char by value and then again copy this value to the required cell.

Comment: @mkmostafa What is your *actual* problem? Is it one of "efficiency" or optimization? Copying a character is trivial and will only be noticeable if you do it a few million times in a short amount of time. I think you need to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and think about how it relates to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Passing every character of a string by value to a function is just as not-okay as passing the entire string by value. That is, in both cases you should prefer some alternative, where the entire string doesn't have to be copied or traversed, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a single character by value is OK because the size of a character is less than the size of a pointer you need to pass by reference. Plus, no copy constructors are invoked for a character.

(That does not mean calling a function for each character in a string is always OK)